# Expletivo é sinônimo de palava de baixo calão?

Tags: significado, semântica

Estava eu navegando no SOpt (StackOverflow Português) quando encontrei essa pergunta:
[É aceito o uso de expletivos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/685/%C3%89-aceito-o-uso-de-expletivos?)

Fui procurar o significado da palavra e encontrei:

> "Diz-se da palavra ou expressão empregada para produzir ênfase,
> realce"
>
> "Diz-se de ou elemento de caráter estilístico us. por puro realce (p.ex., a palavra *só* em *olha só o que aconteceu* ; a partícula *se* em *foi-se embora* )."

E pensei, qual o problema de usar expletivos no SOpt, então?
Foi aí que lendo a publicação ficou claro que ele se referia a palavras de baixo calão (vulgo 'palavrões').

Não conhecia a palavra, mas para aqueles que a conhecem, ela é comumente usada para descrever palavrões?

Fiquei me indagando se seria o mesmo caso de [proselitismo](http://g1.globo.com/Noticias/PapanoBrasil/0,,MUL35876-8524,00.html), que acabou adquirindo uma conotação negativa com o tempo.

Comment: "expletivo" nunca esteve no meu vocabulário e não conhecia o seu significado até agora.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[***Expletivo***](http://www.aulete.com.br/expletivo) não é, pelo menos por enquanto, sinónimo de palavrão, como se pode ver pela definição apresentada na pergunta. O que aconteceu foi que o perguntador no SOpt usou *expletivo* com o significado corrente da palavra inglesa ***expletive***, com a qual o perguntador está claramente familiarizado. Veja-se que ele faz até referência aos ["expletivos em sites de língua inglesa"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/685/%C3%89-aceito-o-uso-de-expletivos?).

O sentido original de *expletive* (a primeira ocorrência conhecida é de 1612) está relacionado com o significado formal em português. Resumindo a definição de [***expletive*** no Merriam-Webster online](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expletive): palavra que preenche um espaço vago sem contribuir para o significado, como *it* em *make it clear which you prefer*. No princípio do século XIX, *expletive* foi aplicado especificamente a um palavrão (meu Oxford Dictionary em papel). É possível usar palavrões como expletivos. Por exemplo, em *tropecei na porra do degrau*, *porra* não acrescenta significado, meramente realça. Na linguagem corrente atual, *expletive* é usado praticamente só com o significado de palavrão. Muitos dicionários, como este [Oxford](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/expletive) ou este [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/expletive), dão apenas esse significado.

O perguntador do SOpt não foi o primeiro a usar *expletivo* com significado de palavrão. Vejam por exemplo este [artigo de 2011](http://artedatraducao.blogspot.pt/2011/11/traducao-audiovisual-e-censura.html):

> Agora, para a segunda temporada, a BBC pediu à produtora responsável pela tradução para amenizar os ***palavrões***. A instrução é a de que, quando um ***expletivo*** comportar diversas traduções possíveis, é melhor "pecar pelo excesso de cautela" em vez de optar pela forma mais forte.